# Matplotlib: How to animate a growing series of random numbers?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, numbers

I'm trying to animate a growing series of random numbers using Matplotlib and MoviePy.

I would like this series:

- to continue to the next line once it has reached the end of the previous line
- to change completely every time it grows by 1 (generates a new sequence)

The whole thing should look like this:

[image]
So far the only thing I could do is:

[image]

*(ridiculous... I know)*

```
from moviepy.video.io.bindings import mplfig_to_npimage
import moviepy.editor as mpy

def moving_numbers(t):
    tf = plt.figure()
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.text(t, 1, np.random.randint(0, 9), fontsize = 24)
    return mplfig_to_npimage(tf)

animation =  mpy.VideoClip(moving_numbers, duration = 2)
animation.write_gif("tf.gif", fps=20)
```

Any idea how I could improve this snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would a pure matplotlib implementation of a random number animation as desired in the question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
import textwrap

nc = 9 # number of characters per line
nl = 6 # number of lines

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
ax.axis("off")

text = ax.text(0,1,"", ha="left", va="top", size=16,
               transform=ax.transAxes)
tw = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=nc)

def update(i):
    h = np.random.randint(0,10,size=i).astype(str)
    t = "".join(h)
    t = tw.fill(t)
    text.set_text(t)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=nc*nl+1, interval=100)
ani.save("anim.gif", writer="imagemagick")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I should have emphasized the fact that I wanted to animate using PyMovie only, I find the quality of the animation far better.

Comment: The image you show in the question is rather pixelated while the animation produced in this answer does not show such artifacts. I would not consider quality a reason not to use matplotlib. But if there are other reasons to use moviepy, feel free to do so; I would not expect the solution to be very different, just that I don't have it available and cannot provide a working example.

Comment: You're right, the GIF is indeed pixelated. That's odd because on my Jupyter Notebook the output is sharp and clean. I liked PyMovie better because it is significantly faster.

Comment: Speed is not a concern when exporting the animation. You may use the `fps` argument to set the desired framerate to something really high, e.g. `ani.save("anim.gif", writer="imagemagick", fps=200)`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer, but using your code, you would have something like that:

```
digits_per_line = 9
new_digits_every_second = 3
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=digits_per_line)

def moving_numbers(t):
    n_digits = int(new_digits_every_second * t)
    digits = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n_digits).astype(str)
    number = "".join(digits)
    wrapped_number = wrapper.fill(number)
    tf = plt.figure()
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.text(0, 0, wrapped_number, fontsize=24)
    return mplfig_to_npimage(tf)
```

**edit:** Using @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's technique to avoid redrawing every time:

```
digits_per_line = 9
new_digits_every_second = 3
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=digits_per_line)

tf = plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
text = plt.text(0, 0, '', a="left", va="top", fontsize=24)

def moving_numbers(t):
    n_digits = int(new_digits_every_second * t)
    digits = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n_digits).astype(str)
    number = "".join(digits)
    wrapped_number = wrapper.fill(number)
    text.set_text(wrapped_number)
    return mplfig_to_npimage(tf)
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. In the second snippet you should replace `wrapped_number` by `""` and also specify `ha="left", va="top"` in `text` and everything should work fine.